# How to add a number in String without using the StringBuilder

Tags: java, string

Say I have A String s = "HOWAREYOU". I want to add number 2 after every two letters so s becomes "HO2AR2EY2OU2". I managed to do it on my own by using the StringBuilder but need to do it without using it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("HelloHowAreYou");
    int i = 2;

    while (i <= str.length()) {
        str.insert(i, "2");
        i = i + 3;
    }

    System.out.println(str.toString());
}
```

Comment: Try to do it on your own and if you encounter a specific issue that you can't find information about on this site or in the documentation then you can ask about that here.

Comment: Get all characters from the string in an ArrayList and use the same approach.

Comment: Just in case you actually have no idea how to do it, here is a tip for one way to do it: `substring`

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Result is `HO2WA2RE2YO2U`, not `HO2AR2EY2OU2`, and can easily be done using regular expression: `s = "HOWAREYOU".replaceAll("..", "$02")`

Comment: If you don't want to use `StringBuilder`, directly or indirectly, then you have to create a `char[]` of the right size (input + 50%), build up the characters of the result, then create a string from the `char[]`. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/4Y3Flu).

Comment: Thank you but I am confused how you used the .replaceAll method. The first parameter should be in the the old String, right? What does ".."  and what does "$0" mean/do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "HelloHowAreYou";
    int frequency = 2;
    String insertCharacter = "2";
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % frequency == 0) {
            newString += str.substring(i, i + 1) + insertCharacter;
        } else {
            newString += str.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code:

```
      public static void main(String[] args)
  {

       String str = "HelloHowAreYou";

       int i = 1;
       int j = 2;

       while ( i <= str.length() )
       {
           if(i%j == 0){

               str = str.substring(0, i)+"2"+str.substring(i, str.length());
               j = j+3;
           }
           i++;
       }

       System.out.println( str );
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using some methods provided by `String` class.

```
String s = "HOWAREYOU";
s = String.join("2", s.split("(?<=\\G..)")); \\HO2WA2RE2YO2U
```